# NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter]

Tags: android, firebase, proguard, google-cloud-firestore

I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter for populating my UI. But I am getting below error with the latest build. Note I am getting this exception only in proguard enabled apk.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [class com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter]
    at android.arch.lifecycle.j.a(Lifecycling.java:111)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.j.c(Lifecycling.java:130)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.j.b(Lifecycling.java:119)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.j.c(Lifecycling.java:145)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.j.b(Lifecycling.java:119)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.j.a(Lifecycling.java:57)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.h$a.(LifecycleRegistry.java:346)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.h.a(LifecycleRegistry.java:162)
    at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.(FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java:37)
    at com.ecom.products.ProductsAdapter.(ProductsAdapter.kt:31)
    at com.ecom.products.j.a(ProductsFragment.kt:48)
```

So I made my `ProductsAdapter`, `ProductHolder` and `ProductsFragment` public classes.

Below are my proguard rules:

```
-keep class com.ecom.products.ProductHolder
-keep class com.ecom.products.ProductsAdapter
-keep class com.ecom.products.ProductsFragment
-keepclassmembers class com.ecom.products.ProductsFragment { *; }
-keep class com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
-keepclassmembers class com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter { *; }
```

My dependencies versions:

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0'
kapt 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0'
```

Hope I can get some help.

Comment: is the productholder an inner class?

Comment: No all classes are separate classes with public access.

Comment: Just in case: please check if you are using the latest kapt implementation (so you have the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in your `build.gradle` file.
The original implementation that is enabled by default is deprecated and should not be used (it will be removed completely soon after the Kotlin 1.2 release).